# I have been trying to make an error handling on Coldfusion, everything is working good but I am not able to get the current session username

Tags: coldfusion, session-variables

1. Application.cfm

   ```
        <cfapplication name="AppError" clientmanagement="Yes" sessionmanagement="Yes" 
          clientstorage="cookie">
          <cferror type="exception" template="ExpressError.cfm" exception="expression">
         <cferror type="exception" template="DatabaseError.cfm" exception="database">
   ```
2. ExpressError.cfm

   ```
     <cfoutput>
        Sorry! Internal Error Occurred!

       <cfsavecontent variable="errortext">
             <div class="container">
          <table class="err">
          <tr>
          <th>URL</th><td>#cgi.server_name##cgi.script_name#</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <th>Message</th><td>#Error.message#</td>
          </tr>
           <tr>
              <th>Diagnostics</th><td>#Error.Diagnostics#</td>
          </tr>
            <tr>
             <th>Template</th><td>#Error.TEMPLATE#</td>
            </tr>
         </table>
            </div>  
              </cfsavecontent>

       <cfmail to="xxx@xxx.com" from="yyy@yyyy.com" subject="Error : #Error.message#" type="html">
           <HTML>
             <head>
                  <style type="text/css">
                    <cfinclude template="Style/errorstyle.css">
                </style>
                </head>
                <body>
                #errortext#
               </body>
                 </HTML>
                 </cfmail>
            </cfoutput>
   ```
3. DatabaseError.cfm

   ```
         <cfoutput>
           Sorry! Internal Error Occurred!

           <cfsavecontent variable="errortext">
              <div class="container">

            <table class="err">
            <tr>
        <th>Application</th><td>#elmsapp#</td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
        <th>URL</th><td>#cgi.server_name##cgi.script_name#</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
        <th>Message</th><td>#Error.message#</td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Diagnostics</th><td>#Error.Diagnostics#</td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
            <th>Template</th><td>#Error.TEMPLATE#</td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
            <th>Sql</th><td>#Error.RootCause.Sql#</td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
            <th>DataSource</th><td>#Error.RootCause.DataSource#</td>
            </tr>
         <tr>
            <th>RemoteAddress</th><td>#Error.RemoteAddress#</td>
                </tr>
         </table>
          </div>    
           </cfsavecontent>

         <cfmail to="xxx@xxx.com" from="yyy@yyyyy.com" subject="Error: #Error.message#" type="html">
            <HTML>
              <head>
             <style type="text/css">
                <cfinclude template="Style/errorstyle.css">
           </style>
          </head>
         <body>
           #errortext#
            </body>
           </HTML>
         </cfmail>

          </cfoutput>
   ```
4. test.cfm

   ```
          <cfoutput>#sdfssfsdf#</cfoutput>
   ```
5. user.cfm

   ```
           <cfoutput> #trim(session.auth_user)# </cfoutput>
   ```

So when i run test.cfm, i am getting a correct email saying "Variable SDFSSFSDF is undefined." but when i run user.cfm, i am getting an email saying "Element AUTH_USER is undefined in SESSION.".
Point is when i delete application.cfm, user.cfm page gives the correct username of the session but with application.cfm in place...it gives an error. I think i need to define the sessiom.auth_user but how and where is the question.
Would appreciate if someone could please help me out. Thanks

Comment: Your thought about having to define a variable before you can use or display it is correct.  Also, it may or may not be relevent that auth_user is the name of a variable in the cgi scope.

Comment: Thanks!...But where and how do I define?

Comment: You’re right that you need to define session.auth_user. The code you are presenting is extremely old CFML. About 15 years ago, CFML apps started switching over to application.cfc, which can have a method onSessionStart(), which is where you would define session variables at the start of a session. If my memory is correct, I think you simply add <cfparam name=“session.auth_user” default=“”> after your cfapplication call. You can also just define it when it needs to be set and use StructKeyExists(session, “auth_user”) in your error handler.